# Javascript, jquery for Owl Carousel: rearrange conditions, change items

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

On this page, that I uploaded through https://mappingforyou.eu/fusion/ , Owl Carousel calls on Flickr to provide some photos according to a list of National Parks, in the variable "cached", and the caption is the National park name

[image]

I would like to remove any reference to these parks and instead, add each item of photos2, with the jpg in "photo" and the caption in "caption", in that carousel which seems to bein the buildhtml function, but it has a parkname value and i have several values to provide.

[image]

So far, I'm very unsuccessful. I have trouble too, understanding some things in this code.
If the provided info isn't enough, or well written, please ask some additional info and I'd be glad to edit my question, with your help.

```
var photos;
var gallery_items;

function callFlickr(f, parkName) {
        var bbox = turf.extent(f.geometry).join(",");
        var tags = parkName.split(" ");
        tags.push("park");
        tags.push("national");
        tags = tags.join(",");
        $.ajax({
                url : flickr_config.url,
                //jsonp : "jsonFlickrApi",
                dataType : 'json',
                data : {
                        api_key : flickr_config.key,
                        tags : tags,
                        bbox : bbox,
                        format : 'json',
                        method : 'flickr.photos.search',
                        per_page : flickr_config.maxNumImages,
                        nojsoncallback : 1
                }
        }).done(function (resp) {
                queue_length += 1;
                if(resp.stat !== "ok") {
                        if(queue_length == current_req_length) {
                                buildHtml(parkName)
                        }
                        return;
                }
                photos = [];
                $.each(resp.photos.photo, function (i, v) {
                        photos.push("https://farm" + v.farm + ".staticflickr.com/" + v.server + "/" + v.id + "_" + v.secret + "_n.jpg");
                });
                // add to cache
                cached[parkName] = photos;
                current_gallery[parkName] = photos;
                if(queue_length == current_req_length) {
                        buildHtml(parkName);
                }
        });
}

// builds html for carousel
function buildHtml() {
       //  var gallery_items;
        var gallery_container = $("<div />", {
                id : 'owl-slider',
                class : 'own-carousel'
        });
        var list = [];
        $.each(current_gallery, function (park, photos) {
                list.push("<a class='park-item' href='' target='_blank'>" + park + "</a>");
                $.each(photos, function (idx, photo) {
                        var div = $("<div />", {
                                class : 'thumbnail'
                        });

                        div.on('mouseover', function (e) {
                                highlightPark(park);
                        });
                        div.on('mouseout', function (e) {
                                $.each(np_geo.getLayers(), function (i, l) {
                                        l.setStyle(style());
                                });
                        });

                        var title = $("<span />", {
                                html : "<h2><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-globe inverse'></span>  " + park + " National Park</h2>",
                                class : 'parkname-title'
                        });

                        var fullPhoto = photo.replace("n.jpg", "b.jpg");
                
                        var link = $("<a />", {
                                "data-lightbox" : "image-" + idx,
                                "data-title" : park + " (courtesy of Flickr)",
                                href : fullPhoto
                        });

                        var img = $("<img />", {
                                src : photo
                        });

                        link.append(img);
                        div.append(link);
                        div.append(title);
                        gallery_container.append(div);
                });
        });

        list = list.join(' | ');
        $("#parkslist").html(list);
        $(".park-item").on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                highlightPark(e.target.text);
        })
        $("#slider").empty();
        $("#slider").append(gallery_container);
        $("#owl-slider").owlCarousel({
                margin : 10,
                autoWidth : true,
                stagePadding : 50
        });
}
```

Comment: Note there is a huge banner on the Owl Carousel [GitHub page](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2) that says: **YEAH SO THIS IS PRETTY MUCH DEAD, DO YOURSELF A FAVOR AND SWITCH TO tiny-slider**

Comment: @Yogi then do you think it's possible in jquery or something, to create a string that concatenates some divs that includes stuff from my photo2 variable ? the tiny slider page advises to do some divs. how do you think i can do that please ?

Comment: i'd love to edit that outerHTML out of the div variable with all data from photos2, though

Comment: I looked at the "fusion" page. It appears to be very old as all the libraries are 5-10 years out of date. So I assume you did not originally code the page, but are trying to modify it to fit your requirements? Frankly, it would be significant work to upgrade the page because it would require rewriting the entire page. So even though Owl Carousel is outdated, it might be better to keep it and focus on making the minimum changes needed to have the page do what you want.  Stack Overflow can help answer very specific problems that you might encounter, but the questions must be very focused.